# How do I create a line chart in visual studio?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vba, visual-studio-2012

I want to create a line chart in visual studio as shown in the picture in Excel below:

[image: Table with line chart]

Before I went to Visual Studio, I tried to create a table in Microsoft access as shown in the picture below, but I am still not sure of the steps to create a chart in visual basic:

[image]

Then, in visual studio, I continued by adding a report viewer and DataGridView. In the picture shown below you can see my Form1 interface:

[image: Table and report viewer]

Here are the settings in my report chart:
[image]

However the result produces this:
[image]

Here's the code :

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Table1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Table1BindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me._5DataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the '_5DataSet.Table1' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.Table1TableAdapter.Fill(Me._5DataSet.Table1)

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()

End Sub

Private Sub Chart1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub ReportViewer1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportViewer1.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

My question is, how do I make change this so that the x-axis shows the values 1 to 24 with all the values in the chart the same as my plot in excel?

Comment: Are you writing this in `Visual Basic` or `C#`? Please show your code.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft visual studio 2013

Comment: I edited to show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the settings in the report chart, I would suggest moving OLD and LimitPower to the "Values" section in the chart data and moving time to series groups.

Comment: Hi, when i try it there is still no any point plotted in the chart.

Comment: here's the image:

http://i.imgur.com/Rrdpg60.png 

is there any ways to put the exactly values on the chart?

Comment: Hi, there's some improvement here 
![IMAGE](http://i.imgur.com/dxeXlUE.png)

How to shows the line?

Comment: I think that might be under the chart settings, usually you have a couple options there that you might explore

Comment: Do i need 3rd party apps?